# Integrating $\int \sin^3{x} \cos^2{2x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Is there a trick to this integral?
$$\int \sin^3{x} \cos^2{2x}\,dx$$

I've tried to solve this by integration by parts and by expanding $\cos^2{2x}$ but these seem to make it more complicated.

Is there something I'm missing like a clever substitution or using the trigonometric identities?

Comment: One trick here is to peel off one $\sin x$, then convert everything else to an expression in $\cos x$. This sets you up for a $u$-substitution.

Comment: On second thought what @Blue said would be easier

Answer (score 2):

With $c:=\cos x$, the integral becomes polynomial,

$$I=-\int (1-c^2)(2c^2-1)^2dc.$$

Then

$$\int(4c^6-8c^4+5c^2-1)\,dc$$ is immediate.